# Is it possible to declare the function's attribute outside of where it is defined? (GCC)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, function-attributes

In GCC, many function attributes can be used to give syntax to the compiler for useful optimization/profiling of the code.

Helpful link: https://www.acrc.bris.ac.uk/acrc/RedHat/rhel-gcc-en-4/function-attributes.html

For instance, the typical usage of function attribute would look something like this:

---

```
// foo.h
__attribute__((no_instrument_function)) void foo();
```

```
// test.c 
// gcc -finstrument-functions test.c -o test 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
void foo() { printf("Foo\n"); }
int main() { foo(); return 0; }
```

Compiling the above code will insert `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit` **only** in `main` function, and avoid inserting them in `foo`.

---

Now I wonder whether it is possible to declare a function attribute(s) of target function(s) in a separate file.

For instance, if  I have `foo.h` and `bar.h` **without** the attribute, is there a way to have a single file that gives attributes to both `foo` and `bar` functions?
For instance, I tried to solve this question by doing something like this (incorrect solution):

---

```
// attributes.c
void foo() __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
void bar() __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
```

```
// bar.h
void bar();
```

```
// foo.h
void foo();
```

```
// test.c 
// gcc -finstrument-functions attributes.c test.c -o test 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
void foo() { printf("Foo\n"); }
void bar() { printf("Bar\n"); }
int main() { foo(); return 0; }
```

---

The use case or the reason I am trying to solve this problem is that, unlike these microbenchmarks, I am trying to apply function attributes to a much larger program with many source/header files. In other words, there are many functions that I wish to declare function attributes for many functions that are spread across different files, and I think it is a lot easier to create a single file and insert that into the `Makefile`.

I think I could create a script to scan through the folder and add the attributes automatically (using regex) or manually by inserting the code. Still, I am exploring whether there is a cleaner solution to this question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remember that .c files are compiled independently of each other. If a file is compiled without knowledge of this attribute, I don't think you can slap it on later at the linking stage (at least for most attributes?). Plus, I'm not sure how this is different from inserting the attributes in headers; you have to parse C++ code one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GCC documentation says “[Compatible attribute specifications on distinct declarations of the same function are merged.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)” That means you can declare an attribute in one declaration (such as the first one in a translation unit) and omit it in a later declaration (including the function definition), and the attribute will be merged into the later declaration.

However, you cannot merely put them into a separate source code file, as you do with `attribute.c`, and then compile them separately from the other source code. The compiler must see the attribute when it is compiling the source code that is affected by it. You could put them in a file named `attribute.h` and then include `attribute.h` in your other header files.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the proposed solution. From what I have tried and looked into, this is the best way to do it. I noticed things become a bit more complicated when I try to apply this method for larger programs, but I think at this point, it is probably better to create a GCC plugin or some other methods that could streamline it a bit better.